# How to debug PLSQL procedure being executed by a parallel task in PLSQL developer

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have a plsql procedure which is using DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE to create a new task, create the chunks by row_id and then execute the task.

```
procedure test as
begin
      DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_task('newtask');
      DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.create_chunks_by_rowid('newtask','PEEUSH','NEWTABLE',TRUE,1000);
      DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE.run_task(task_name      => 'newtask',
                                    sql_stmt       => 'begin  PEEUSH.test2(:start_id,:end_id); end;',
                                    language_flag  => DBMS_SQL.NATIVE,
                                     parallel_level => 4); 

end;
```

Now I want to debug this from PLSQL developer, but as soon as execution reaches at run_task. It comes out. Is there any way step into the test2 procedure in PLSQL developer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need the remote debugger, `DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP`. Unfortunately PL/SQL Developer doesn't currently support this and you'll need to install another tool that does, such as [SQL Developer](http://barrymcgillin.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/remote-debugging-with-sql-developer.html).

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if it's really sensible (or possible) to do such debugging in pl-sql procedure running via DBMS_PARALLEL_EXECUTE at 4 parallel threads.

I would run and debug `begin  PEEUSH.test2(:start_id,:end_id); end;` separately on a small set of data to check any runtime exception.

However, what could be desirable is to see if TASK ran successfully or not.

```
-- To monitor task
select * from USER_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASKS;

-- To monitor chunks
select * from USER_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_CHUNKS;
```